# Display DateTimeOffset type in Telerik's RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to display DateTimeOffset type in the grid, but noticed that, the grid automatically hides these types of columns, which gives me the idea that it's not supported...

Also, if this is not supported, would it be possible to add support to it, by extending some base class?

Note: I'm using DataTable as datasource.

Comment: DateTimeOffset in .Net is an object, how were you hoping to display that in a column?  Do you have any code to show?

Comment: That's also an MSSQL column type...